# $\varphi$ monotone,continuous on $[0,1]$. Show $\varphi$ is AC, iff for any borel $f_n\to f$ in $L^1$,$\{\varphi(f_n)\}$ converges in measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

[image]Let $\varphi$ be monotonic and continuous on $[0,1]$. Show it is AC, iff for any borel sequence $f_n$ that converges in $L^1$ the sequences $\varphi(f_n)$ converges in measure.

The forward direction follows from the fact that $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$ implies convergence in measure and continuity preserves convergence in measure on finite measures. The backwards direction is the one that is giving me a little more trouble.

Since $\varphi$ is monotonic (WLOG its increasing) all we have to show is that  $\nexists x$ s. t. $\int_{0}^{x}\varphi'\lt\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)$. However I do not really know how to do that.

Any hints would be highly appreciated.

Comment: On what space are the functions $f_n$ supposed to live?  You just said $L^1$ but you didn't specify over what measure space.  In particular it's not clear whether it's supposed to be a space of finite measure. Also, a general $L^1$ function may take values outside $[0,1]$ so how does $\varphi(f_n)$ make sense?  Please clarify the question.

Comment: @NateEldredge Its  on $L^[0,1]$ I took it basically verbatim for the past qual i was solving so I do not know what the "correct" formulation is. I added the original phrasing.

Comment: So, there's still the issue that if $\phi$ is only defined on $[0,1]$ then $\phi \circ f_n$ is in general not defined.  And if we take the second part as "for any sequence of Borel functions $f_n : [0,1] \to [0,1]$" then as PhoemueX points out, it is not true.  My inclination would be to either find someone locally who may know what was meant, or else to drop it from your studying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you showed is that the claim is always true, even without assuming that $\varphi$ is AC. Therefore, the converse direction is not true (take your favourite non AC monotonic continuous function, e.g. the devil's staircase).

---

A correct characterization (at least for the case that $\varphi$ is *strictly* increasing) is as follows:
Assume that $\varphi : [0,1] \to [a,b]$ is *strictly* increasing,
so that $\varphi^{-1} : [a,b] \to [0,1]$ is well-defined.
Then $\varphi$ is AC if and only if whenever $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$,
then $f_n \circ \varphi^{-1} \to f \circ \varphi^{-1}$ in measure.

Indeed, if $f_n \to f$ in measure, then it is not too hard to see
(with $\lambda$ denoting the Lebesgue measure) that
\begin{align*}
  \lambda \bigl(\{ x : |f_n \circ \varphi^{-1}(x) - f \circ \varphi^{-1} (x)| > \epsilon \}\bigr)
  & = \lambda\bigl( \varphi ( \{ y : |f_n (y) - f (y)| > \epsilon \} ) \bigr) \\
  & = \int_0^1
      \varphi'(t) \cdot 1_{|f_n(t) - f(t)| > \epsilon}
    \, d t
  & \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0
\end{align*}
for arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$ by the dominated convergence theorem,
since the indicator function converges to zero in measure.

Conversely, suppose towards a contradiction that $\varphi$ is not absolutely continuous.
By definition, this means that there is some $\epsilon > 0$ such that for each $n \in \Bbb{N}$
there is a pairwise disjoint family of intervals $(a_i^{(n)}, b_i^{(n)}) \subset [0,1]$
($i = 1,\dots,m_n$) such that $\sum_{i=1}^{m_n} (b_i^{(n)} - a_i^{(n)}) < \frac{1}{n}$,
but $\sum_{i=1}^{m_n} \bigl(\varphi(b_i^{(n)}) - \varphi(a_i^{(n)})\bigr) \geq \epsilon$.
This means if we define $f_n := \sum_{i=1}^{m_n} 1_{(a_i^{(n)}, b_i^{(n)})}$, then $f_n \to 0$
in $L^1$, but $f_n \circ \varphi^{-1} = \sum_{i=1}^{m_n} 1_{\bigl(\varphi(a_i^{(n)}), \varphi(b_i^{(n)})\bigr)}$
does not converge to zero in measure.

Comment: Comment: The claim is probably true if one considers $f_n \circ \varphi$ instead of $\varphi(f_n)$.

Comment: Are you sure? A quick from scratch attempt would be: assume $\phi(0)=0,\ \phi(1)=1$ and $\phi$ is increasing. If $\phi$ is not absolutely continuous, then there is an $0<\epsilon<1$ and for each integer $n$, disjoint intervals $(I_{nk})_k$ such that $\sum_k|I_{nk}|<\frac{1}{n}$ but $\sum_k|\phi(x_{k+1})-\phi(x_k)|>\epsilon$

Define $f_n:=\sum_k\chi_{I_{nk}}.$ Then $\|f_n\|_1\to 0.$ But for any $\delta>0,\  \lambda\left (\{x:f_n\circ \phi(x)>\delta\}\right)=\lambda\left(\{x:\phi(x)\subseteq A_n\}\right)\rightarrow 0$ also So these $(f_n)$ won't work.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Matematleta: My last comment was not completely correct. I now added a corrected version of my comment to the answer.

Comment: That's what I got for the only if part, too. Nice proof of the forward direction. +1